# Are there better method to update a column in my database table rather than using MySQL Schedule events?

Tags: mysql, node.js, performance, express, scheduled-tasks

Frontend: Reactjs
Backend: Nodejs + Express
Database: Mysql Workbench
Hosting: Linode

Now I have an event that is scheduled to run every 2 seconds to update the status column. However, I am worried that the event might affect the performance of the server. Hence, I want to hear suggestions from you guys on what I should do.

I want to update the status column based on the start date & end date data in the database. The SQL code that I used for Mysql events is:

```
CREATE EVENT update_status
ON SCHEDULE EVERY 2 SECOND
DO
UPDATE `practiceme`.`events` as e
set `e`.`status` = 
CASE
WHEN CURRENT_DATE > `e`.`eventEnd` THEN 'Past'
WHEN CURRENT_DATE < `e`.`eventStart` THEN 'Upcoming'
WHEN CURRENT_DATE > `e`.`eventStart` AND CURRENT_DATE < `e`.`eventEnd` THEN 'Ongoing'
ELSE `status`
END
```

My database table "events" stores the start and end date.

[image: Database table]

Comment: Seems to me that the status does not need to be a column, you can work that out as part of any query that would look at this table

Comment: Beware!  If, for some odd reason, one Event does not finish until the next Event fires off, you could get into a nasty situation.  I would rather have a program 'continually' checking than risk  an Event (or cron) that fails to finish before the next.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's always a good idea to filter your records. What are the possible changes and when:

- from Ongoing to Past (if it was Ongoing previously and ended)
- from Upcoming to Ongoing (if it was Upcoming previously and started)

So:

```
CREATE EVENT update_status
ON SCHEDULE EVERY 2 SECOND
DO
UPDATE `practiceme`.`events` as e
set `e`.`status` = 
CASE
WHEN CURRENT_DATE > `e`.`eventEnd` THEN 'Past'
WHEN CURRENT_DATE < `e`.`eventStart` THEN 'Upcoming'
WHEN CURRENT_DATE > `e`.`eventStart` AND CURRENT_DATE < `e`.`eventEnd` THEN 'Ongoing'
ELSE `status`
END
WHERE 
((`e`.`status` <> 'Past') AND (`e`.`eventEnd` < CURRENT_DATE)) OR
((`e`.`status` <> 'Ongoing') AND (`e`.`eventStart` > CURRENT_DATE))
```

It is also a good idea to convert `status` into an `enum` and make sure that `status` defaults to Upcoming.

Comment: what does the where clause do? Also, will this affects my server performance?

Comment: @jack the `where` clause filters your data set to be updated. You do not want to evaluate the case-when for the majority of your records. It will likely improve your performance, but you will only know this factually if you actually measure it and check the query plan. A lot depends on your schema which you did not share, so I cannot be sure. But, it is a best practice to narrow down the records at the update to update only what's needed to be updated. Reads are quicker than writes, so make sure you filter your read rather than write everything.

Comment: @jack If this answer helped you solve the problem, then you may consider accepting it as the correct answer.

Comment: 1 last question, so can I say my previous method updates every record for the status column, and your answer above updates the records only when it is needed to be updated?

Comment: @jack that's correct. We are speaking about prefiltering the records to be updated in the current case and then updating only what's needed to be updating, while in the original code we were updating all records.

Answer (score 2):

Instead of bombarding the database with updates, you can query the status on demand. In fact, you don't even need to store the status:

```sql
SELECT *,
       CASE
           WHEN CURRENT_DATE > `e`.`eventEnd` THEN 'Past'
           WHEN CURRENT_DATE < `e`.`eventStart` THEN 'Upcoming'
           ELSE 'Ongoing'
      END AS `status`
FROM  `practiceme`.`events` e
-- Add a where caluse depending on what you need to query
```

Comment: I understand your point, according to which the `status` is a functional dependency. However, the asker may have a good reason to do it like this, maybe along the lines of timezones, daylight saving time and so on the issue of what scheduled event started and what ended becomes less obvious.

Comment: a [generated column](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/create-table-generated-columns.html) seems to be a better option?

Comment: @Luuk to quote the link you provided (bolding my own for emphasis): "Generated column expressions must adhere to the following rules. An error occurs if an expression contains disallowed constructs. 
Literals, deterministic built-in functions, and operators are permitted. A function is deterministic if, given the same data in tables, multiple invocations produce the same result, independently of the connected user. **Examples of functions that are nondeterministic and fail this definition**: CONNECTION_ID(), CURRENT_USER(), **NOW()**."

Comment: Thank you all for replying, my status column will be used to add or multiply the player's score if the topicId is ongoing.

Comment: OK, I forgot that...., But anyway doing the update only ones a day, (and maybe a trigger on the change of `eventEnd` and/or `eventStart` will cut down the number of update from 43200 to far less database activity.

Comment: Be aware of the difference between `TIMESTAMP` (effectively UTC, converted from/to localtime) and `DATETIME` (what the clock on the wall says when the `INSERT` is performed).  This should fix the concern.  Then compute the status `SELECT`.  A variant (to a Generated column) is to have a Stored Function to calculate the status as during the Select.